# Minimum amount for beracha achorona

Tags: halacha, blessing, halacha-theory, shiurim-measurements, orach-chaim

According to Halacha what is the Minimum amount to eat before Jews are obligated to recite a beracha achorona? Is it a disputed question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SA 210:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.210.1?lang=bi)

> האוכל פחות מכזית בין מפת בין משאר אוכלים והשותה פחות מרביעית בין מיין בין משאר משקים מברך תחלה ברכה הראויה לאותו המין ולאחריו אינו מברך כלל ויש מסתפקים לומ' שעל דבר שהוא כברייתו כגון גרגיר של ענב או של רימון שמברכין לאחריו אע"פ שאין בו כזית לכך נכון ליזהר שלא לאכול בריה פחות מכזית: הגה ולא מיקרי בריה אלא אם אכלו כמות שהוא אבל אם לקח הגרעין ממנו לא מקרי ברי' [הר"י פרק כיצד מברכין וב"י בשם רשב"א]  ויש מסתפקין עוד בברכה אחרונה של יין אם מברכין אותו על כזית לכן טוב ליזהר שלא לשתות  (אלא)  פחות מכזית או רביעית:

> One who eats less than an olives-worth, whether it's from bread or it's from other foods, or one drinks less than a quarter-log, whether it's from wine or other beverages, one blesses at the outset of blessing that is fit for that particular type and one does not bless a post-consumption blessing at all. And there are some who are unsure whether to say it's on something that it is like its creation, such as a crumb of grape or of a pomegranate that one blesses a post-consumption blessing even though there's not an olive’s-worth of it. Therefore, it is proper to be careful not to eat something less than an olive. And there are some who are further unclear with the post-consumption blessing over wine if one blesses upon it when one drinks only an olive’s-worth. Therefore, it is good to be careful not to drink less than an olive’s-worth or a quarter-log’s-worth

There is another requirement, to eat it within the time frame of kdei achilas pras. The exact timing of this is subject to dispute.

Exactly what can be counted as the kzayis, (for example, a donut that has a lot of air) is also subject to much discussion.